# Latex in Jupyter Notebook iPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I have a python project in jupyter notebook, and I want to display the final output with latex.

```
x = 5
print("The number you have inputted is ", complex(x, y), " ^ 1/", n, sep = '')
```

I want this to be formatted using latex:

[image: Input to be formatted]

---

I read a bunch of forums but the fraction wasn't working for 2digit numbers

```
n=10
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown(rf"""$ { complex(x, y) } ^ \frac{1}{n} $"""))
```

The best I could get:

[image: Input to be formatted]

---

Any suggestions would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly display it as Latex using `Latex`. To keep the curly brackets as literals for Latex you need to use double `{{` `}}`. Otherwise the `\frac` does not obtain the full operands.

```
from IPython.display import display, Latex

x=1
y=0
n=10

display(Latex(rf'$ { complex(x, y) } ^\frac{{1}}{{{n}}}$'))
```

Output in Jupyterlab:
[image]

Comment: OP wants to print the formatted string... The above code note giving the desired output for 2-digit number(n)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the jupyprint package: https://pypi.org/project/jupyprint/

You could use the following code:

```
import jupyprint as jp

x=1
y=0
n=10

jp.jupyprint(f"$ {complex(x, y)}" + " ^ \\frac{" + f"{1}" + "}{" + f"{n}" + "} $")
```

[Here is how the output looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QseTT.png)